# access site behind login.microsoftonline oauth2 with python requests

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, python-requests, oauth

trying to login login to a website hosted behind login.microsoftonline.com (think this a Azure cloud deployment) oauth2 site with python requests

How should i go about structuring the request?

Comment: is that a web api or web service that is running ? if so then you should be sending the auth token in the header to the appropriate api endpoint

Comment: it's rendering HTTP retreaved from bitbucket git - not sure on the technology doing this as was setup by 3rd party. What i do know is that it is behind a login.microsoftonline.com page

Comment: @chris, Is the tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/ satisfied you needs?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT not really, that seems to be about setting up a web app on Azure AD. I want to scrape a site that is authenticated by Azure AD. I can't figure out the request response needed with Python requests

Answer (score 0):

@chris, I see you want to access a website via construct a request with access token which got by authentication with OAuth2 on Azure. Please follow the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/#register-your-application-with-your-ad-tenant) to know the OAuth 2.0 authorization flow and how to do it step by step.

Please try to access site manually by browser and use Fiddler to catch the parameters which required in Python request.